# WSO2 EI/ESB : How to use/manage Incoming Header Parameters to use them in second back-end call?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In my case, while calling the process API from Postman, I'm passing the required headers from Postman itself.
Now, the API has two sequential back-end calls, both require same headers.
The headers are working fine for the first back-end call. For the second back-end call, I'm getting "**Authorization error : Missing Credentials**".

I want to use same headers for both back-end calls.

How do I save the incoming headers and pass them to the second back-end call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the transport headers before the first call into a property like below. This would save the property in the message context. **$trp** indicates that we are reading the incoming transport headers.

```
<property expression="$trp:Authorization" name="AuthorizationCode" scope="default"/>
```

After the first call is made, put back the transport header. **$ctx** means that we are reading from the message Context. We are saving it with the scope transport because we want it to be sent as a Transport Header.

```
<property expression="$ctx:AuthorizationCode" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
```

Comment: Will this property save all the multiple incoming Headers from postman? Or do I need to have separate property for every header?

Comment: You need to save the necessary headers and reuse them. You cannot save all the headers at the same time.

Comment: So, do I need to have separate property for every necessary header?

Comment: Yes, you need separate properties.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked as required. I really appreciate your help. Please don't mind if I tag you in some more questions further. :)